# How do I get pages like src/pages/myrootpage.erl to show up at http://mysite.org/myrootpage using nitrogen?

Tags: erlang, nitrogen

Nitrogen does not seem to like pages being at the root url path, only addon paths like /web/ is there some way to get pages to show up at the root url like /mypage ?

Comment: nginx can do it for you. You will need to run it any way, the day you need several sites on the same host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can not do it. You can change what this prefix is, it doesn't have to be '/web', but at the moment there has to be one root element with some name. This may change soon but because Nitrogen currently does not include support for static file sharing then this is the current reality.